TDD when DDD with lots of dependency in information model
The system is designed with entities for each of the business elements. Each entity is represented as a class with methods for its behavior and property for its data. We map the entity to the database in a separate file. Use NHibernate as ORM.
Most of the entities has relations to other entities and these relations is verified when either creating the object, in its constructor, or in the behavior method.
To the problem. Let's assume I'm tasked with adding a new behavior to the entity invoice. In the test I need an invoice in a specific state. But to new up an invoice it requires three dependencies to other entities which each needs more dependencies and so on. Most of these dependencies have nothing to do with the test I'm about to do, but it requires lots of setup.
What would you do?

You could use Test Data Builders so that you don't have to generate a lot of required, but for the test irrelevant, data.
That said, if you actually follow TDD by writing the test before the System Under Test, you might have come to the realization that this kind of design isn't particularly easy to test. Following TDD, then, you should consider a different design that'd be easier to test.
